# Filtering specific data from a group of data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter only specific data in angularjs.

here is my object,

```
$scope.studyTeamObj;
```

In this object,I have object like this

```
{"Study_Team": [
{
  "designation": {
    "Emp_Name": "mdrf",
    "Emp_Id": 2,
    "Designation": "Research Dietitian",
    "DesignationID": 20
  }
}
]
}
```

I want to filter like this.only two datas are enough.How can I do?

```
{
"Study_Team":[
{
  "Emp_Id":1,
  "DesignationID":20,
}
]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [**Angular filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Answer (score 0):

I presume you need an Angular filter without modifying the original object:

```js
var angularApp = angular.module("app", []);
angularApp.filter("studyTeam", function(){
          return function(obj){
              var studyTeamArr = obj.Study_Team;
              return studyTeamArr.map(function(obj){
                       var desig = angular.copy(obj.designation);
                       delete desig.Emp_Name;
                       delete desig.Designation;
                       return desig;

               });
          } });
  
angularApp.controller("angCtrl", function($scope, $filter){

$scope.studyTeamObj = {"Study_Team": [
{
  "designation": {
    "Emp_Name": "mdrf",
    "Emp_Id": 2,
    "Designation": "Research Dietitian",
    "DesignationID": 20
  }
}
]
};



console.log( JSON.stringify( $filter('studyTeam')($scope.studyTeamObj)) );


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="angCtrl">

</div>

</div>
```